# Duplicate terms in that have mutiple parent category

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I am listing some taxonomy terms in view page group by category. Some of the terms have relationship to multiple taxonomy category. I want to display same items more than once in different category on same page. Please help me on this. Thanks

Comment: it's unclear exactly what you mean. can you post a screenshot of the view settings, and perhaps the current results which you want to change?

Comment: @Geoff The terms are related to multiple category. In listing page terms are displaying only once. Terms having more than one category are displaying under title category name separated by commas. 

If term1 related to categoy 1 and category 2 it should display like this

Category 1
Term 1

Category 2
Term 1

Comment: how are the terms related to the categories?